# phpmailer using office 365

Tags: office365, phpmailer

currently i have website with form contact us that send email to me using other account email,

i'm using office 365 and phpmailer to handle it, but there some error if implementin my code.

Error :

```
2020-10-23 08:40:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost

2020-10-23 08:40:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS

2020-10-23 08:40:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost

2020-10-23 08:40:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN

2020-10-23 08:40:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: aW5mb0BvYmYxxxx

2020-10-23 08:40:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: Z3R2Z3hneW55d2xxxxxxxx 2

020-10-23 08:40:58 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [SG2PR06CA0187.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com]

2020-10-23 08:40:58 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

2020-10-23 08:40:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

2020-10-23 08:40:58 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

my code :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'STARTTLS';

$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';

$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->Username = 'info@abc.com';

$mail->Password = 'password';

$mail->Subject = $subject;
```

could someone help me using office 365 in phpmailer?

Comment: Set `SMTPDebug = 2` so that you can see what the server is saying, and show us the results. Also set `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`; the value you made up has no meaning to PHPMailer.

Comment: Hello @Synchro, already set SMTPDebug = 2 and SMTPSecure = 'tls' but the errors still same.

Comment: You need to show us – update your question with the new debug output.

Comment: here the output http://prntscr.com/v7p649

Comment: Please don't post text as images. As the error says, it doesn't like your username and password. This is either because they are wrong, or because they are treating this login with suspicion. I suggest you contact Office365 support if you're certain your credentials are correct – there is nothing wrong with your code. I can tell that you are using a very old version of PHPMailer that contains multiple known vulnerabilities, so [upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) before you do anything else.

Comment: Also make sure there isn't any restriction for this user authentication, e.g: two factor authentication etc.